# Facing issues in JS Filter function in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following lambda expression

```
 if (MyObject.eId.filter(e => e === record.Id).length > 0) 
{
 return;
}
```

This works in all broswers except IE(checked in IE 11)

I tried to convert this to following way but getting syntax error.Please help me to rewrite above function.

```
MyObject.eId.filter(function (e) {
                    if (e === record.Id).length > 0
                    {
                        return;

                    }


                });
```

Comment: Maybe you want to use a polyfill? Take a look at [this](https://caniuse.com/#search=filter).

Comment: For non arrow function your code should look like: `if (
  MyObject.eId.filter(function(e) {
    return e === record.Id;
  }).length > 0
) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your non-arrow function is incorrect: Basically in the callback/predicate of the `.filter` method, you should only check if `e` matches the record ID, without checking for length. The length check should be performed on the returned/filtered array instead:

```
if (MyObject.eId.filter(function(e) { return e === record.Id; }).length > 0) {
    return;
}
```

To break down the complicated one-liner above, you can see it as this:

```
// Step 1: Get an filtered array of IDs that match record ID
var filteredIds = MyObject.eId.filter(function(e) {
    return e === recordId;
});

// Step 2: Check length of filtered array
if (filteredIds.length) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer due to compatibility.

Comment: if (MyObject.eId.filter(function(e) { return e === record.Id }).length > 0) This works fine

Comment: @aniltc Sorry, had a minor typo: should be `function` not `funtion`. Fixed it now.